# Hive Query for ROlling total based on 2 fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have a table a show below

```
    Date | Customer | Count | Daily_Count | ITD_Count  
    d1   |   A      |  3    |  3          |  
    d2   |   B      |  4    |  4          |  
    d3   |   A      |  7    |  16         |  
    d3   |   B      |  9    |  16         |  
    d4   |   A      |  8    |  9          |  
    d4   |   B      |  1    |  9          |
```

Descrption of Fields:

> Date :  date
>   customer : name of customer
>   Count :  # of customers
>   daily_Count :  # of customers on  daily basis calculated as

```
SUM(count) OVER (partition BY date )as Daily_Count
```

Question :
How do I calculate the Running Total or Rolling Total in the ITD_Count ? 
The output should look like

```
Date | Customer | Count | Daily_Count | ITD_Count  
 d1   |   A      |  3    |  3          |  3
 d2   |   B      |  4    |  4          |  7
 d3   |   A      |  7    |  16         |  23
 d3   |   B      |  9    |  16         |  23
 d4   |   A      |  8    |  9          |  31
 d4   |   B      |  1    |  9          |  31
```

I have tried several variations of using the Window functionality.. But hit a road-block in all my attempts.

Attempt 1 ;

```
  SUM(daily_COunt) OVER (partition BY date order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) as ITD_account_linking
```

Attempt 2 :

```
  SUM(daily_COunt) OVER (partition BY date, daily_count order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) as ITD_account_linking
```

and several more attempts following this. :(

Any possible suggestions to guide me in the right direction are welcome.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: just a suggestion try using lead,lag window functions along with your trials

Comment: @KSNidhin : aren't lag() and lead() for proceeding and following rows ? Do you have sample query using lead() and lag() to calculate rolling totals  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Hive Windowing and Analytics functions.

```
SELECT Date, Customer, Count, Daily_Count, 
        SUM(Daily_Count) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS ITD_Count  
FROM table;
```

Comment: Thanks @Rick. but I'm not getting the expected output.   
`Date | Customer | Count | Daily_Count | ITD_Count    
 d1   |   A      |  3    |  3          |  3  
 d2   |   B      |  4    |  4          |  7  
 d3   |   A      |  7    |  16         |  23  
 d3   |   B      |  9    |  16         |  39  
 d4   |   A      |  8    |  9          |  48  
 d4   |   B      |  1    |  9          |  57`